# switching databases in spring petclinic

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to switch from hsql to MySQL in [the spring petclinic sample application](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic/). Can someone show me what I am doing wrong?

I followed the instructions in the petclinic_db_setup_mysql.txt file, and confirmed that the database was created correctly in mysql, but I am getting the following error when I try to run the application on tomcat 7 from within eclipse:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:  
Invalid bean definition with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource  
[spring/business-config.xml]:  
Could not resolve placeholder 'jpa.showSql' in string value "${jpa.showSql}"
```

Here is the relevant code from business-config:

```
   <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
          p:dataSource-ref="dataSource">
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
                  p:database="${jpa.database}" p:showSql="${jpa.showSql}"/>
            <!-- the 'database' parameter refers to the database dialect being used.
                By default, Hibernate will use a 'HSQL' dialect because 'jpa.database' has been set to 'HSQL'
                inside file spring/data-access.properties
             -->
        </property>
        <!-- gDickens: BOTH Persistence Unit and Packages to Scan are NOT compatible, persistenceUnit will win -->
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="petclinic"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="org.springframework.samples.petclinic"/>
    </bean>
```

And here are the contents of data-access.properties:

```
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/petclinic
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.password=some_pwd

# Properties that control the population of schema and data for a new data source
jdbc.initLocation=classpath:db/mysql/initDB.sql
jdbc.dataLocation=classpath:db/mysql/populateDB.sql

# Property that determines which Hibernate dialect to use
# (only applied with "applicationContext-hibernate.xml")
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect

# Property that determines which database to use with an AbstractJpaVendorAdapter
jpa.database=MYSQL
jpa.showSql = true #Added at Dan's suggestion, but new error occurs now.
```

---

### EDIT:

I added jpa.showSql=true as shown above, but now the following new error message is being thrown:

```
ERROR ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:  
Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DataSourceInitializer#0':  
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException:  
Failed to execute database script; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException:  
Could not get JDBC Connection;  
nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

I confirmed that the password to the database is correct(not the bogus one above), and I am able to navigate the database in the MySQL command line client. So the problem is in connecting the web application to the database.  Does anyone have further suggestions?

At Sotirios' request, here is a more complete stack trace of the same error:

```
Nov 28, 2013 1:51:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DataSourceInitializer#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Failed to execute database script; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1512)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Failed to execute database script; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(DatabasePopulatorUtils.java:56)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DataSourceInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(DataSourceInitializer.java:83)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1571)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1509)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(DatabasePopulatorUtils.java:45)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:254)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:182)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:702)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:634)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:488)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:144)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:116)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:103)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:127)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:246)
    ... 36 more
Nov 28, 2013 1:51:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
ERROR ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DataSourceInitializer#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Failed to execute database script; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1512) ~[spring-beans-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458) ~[spring-beans-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296) ~[spring-beans-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223) ~[spring-beans-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293) ~[spring-beans-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628) ~[spring-beans-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932) ~[spring-context-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479) ~[spring-context-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389) ~[spring-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294) ~[spring-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112) [spring-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303) [na:1.6.0_29]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138) [na:1.6.0_29]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [na:1.6.0_29]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [na:1.6.0_29]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [na:1.6.0_29]
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Failed to execute database script; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(DatabasePopulatorUtils.java:56) ~[spring-jdbc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DataSourceInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(DataSourceInitializer.java:83) ~[spring-jdbc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1571) ~[spring-beans-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1509) ~[spring-beans-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80) ~[spring-jdbc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(DatabasePopulatorUtils.java:45) ~[spring-jdbc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:254) ~[tomcat-jdbc-7.0.42.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:182) ~[tomcat-jdbc-7.0.42.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:702) ~[tomcat-jdbc-7.0.42.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:634) ~[tomcat-jdbc-7.0.42.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:488) ~[tomcat-jdbc-7.0.42.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:144) ~[tomcat-jdbc-7.0.42.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:116) ~[tomcat-jdbc-7.0.42.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:103) ~[tomcat-jdbc-7.0.42.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:127) ~[tomcat-jdbc-7.0.42.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111) ~[spring-jdbc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77) ~[spring-jdbc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:246) ~[tomcat-jdbc-7.0.42.jar:na]
    ... 36 common frames omitted
Nov 28, 2013 1:51:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/petclinic] startup failed due to previous errors
```

Comment: Did you comment out the HSQL settings in the data-access.properties?

Comment: don't you need to just add jpa.showSql=true   in your data-access.properties

Comment: @FredericClose Thank you.  I made that change, but a new error is being thrown now.  I described it in an edit to my original posting above.  Do you have any more suggestions?

Comment: @Dan Yes, I commented out the hsql settings. The above is the only uncommented code in my data-access.properties file.

Comment: There must be more to the exception. Can you post it?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thank you.  I just posted a more complete version of the stack trace.  Does this help you see the problem?

Comment: Yes, a `ClassNotFoundException` always indicates that a class is not on your application's classpath. Assuming you are using maven, you will need to add a dependency for the MySQL driver. If you aren't using maven, you will need to download the MySQL driver jar and put it in `WEB-INF/lib`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thank you.  I just went into pom.xml and found a place where the authors of petclinic had commented out the required dependency.  I uncommented it, then commented out the hsql dependency, updated maven for the project, shut down tomcat, then started clean with run as...run on server.  Now it works fine.  Thank you.  If you put it as an answer below, I will mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the original error, [see Dan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20274855/438154). Spring fails right away when it finds a property it cannot resolve, so it didn't get to the next problem until this one was fixed.

For the `ClassNotFoundException`, the answer is always that you are missing a class from your classpath. In this case, you are missing `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`, which you've specified as your JDBC driver class.

Assuming you are using maven, you will need to add a dependency for the MySQL driver. If you aren't using maven, you will need to download the MySQL driver jar and put it in `WEB-INF/lib` directory of your webapp.

Comment: Thank you. +1.  I was able to find and make the changes in pom.xml so quickly because of things you have taught me in other postings.  Your contributions to this site are very much appreciated.  Happy Thanksgiving.

Comment: @CodeMed Just FYI, I'm not ignoring you. I take a look at your questions. I just don't always have an answer.

Comment: @CodeMed Well, what are you looking for?

Comment: In the past you told me what to look for whenever I get a class not found exception in a spring mvc app.  You said that something in particular was always the first thing to check.  `Can you refresh my memory of what to look for?`  I am getting a class not found error for a class that exists.  The app just wont initialize now after I made some unrelated changes. I wanna avoid posting a ton of code in a new question if you know a couple easy things to look for in this common error.

Comment: @CodeMed Simple check is (in Eclipse) to do CTRL + SHIFT + T and search for the type. If it is not found, it's almost definitely nowhere in your workspace.

Comment: Thanks.  I just did that and the class exists.  I made some unrelated changes in my app.  And now the app wont load in tomcat using eclipse run `as..run on server`, and the root error cause is that it cannot find an arbitrary class that has been untouched.

Comment: @CodeMed Careful. Just because it is in the workspace, doesn't mean it's on your app's build path. You should check that too. Additionally, check that there aren't more than one class with the same fully qualified name on the classpath. That can also cause CNFE.

Comment: Thank you for thinking about my problem! I figured it out.  It was caused when I created a new controller class by copying an old controller class. The root problem was that, in the new controller class, I failed to replace `@SessionAttributes(types = someoldclass.class)` with `@SessionAttributes(types = mynewclass.class)`.  Somehow, when the server was trying to load the app, it got confused by the two controllers referring to  `someoldclass`, and instead pointed the error to a completely unrelated class.  But I resolved the error using `@SessionAttributes(types = mynewclass.class)` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Add `jpa.showSql = true` (or `false` depending if you want to see that in console) to your `data-access.properties` file.

Comment: Thank you. +1 for trying to help.  But now a new database error is occurring.  I put a description of it in an edit to my original posting above.  Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I am having a problem with a subsequent modification to the petclinic application.  Do you have a little time to help me with it?  Here is the link to the other problem:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20292152/parameterizing-object-properties

Answer (score 2):

I know it's a bit late but I too faced this issue with Spring's "pet clinic" sample project and found the solution to it.

In order to make the project to work with MySQL, please follow the steps below:

1 - In pom.xml uncomment lines 196 - 200 ( this is to enable MySQL Driver)

```
<!-- For MySql only -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>mysql</groupId>
  <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
  <version>${mysql-driver.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

2 - In data-acccess.properties, change lines 8-9 as below:

```
jdbc.initLocation=classpath:db/mysql/initDB.sql 
jdbc.dataLocation=classpath:db/mysql/populateDB.sql
```

...then comment lines 16 - 22

...and uncomment lines 28 - 34 ( excluding line 33)

That should do it!

Comment: Thank you and +1 for taking the time to add insight to this old question.  FYI, you may be better served to learn spring boot and angularjs instead of the old petclinic because the old petclinic uses jsp, which is not modern technology.  There is aan angularjs branch of the petclinic, but it is an intermediate example.  A beginner can learn more by building up from scratch with the spring boot tutorials and then just add a front end using something from github that you find from googling spring boot angularjs github